# sql self join comparison -- returns duplicate comparison result

Tags: sql, join, self

I have a data like below

```
id value
1  a
1  b
1  a
2  c
2  c
2  d
```

when I query

```
select 
   distinct a.id,
   b.id, 
   a.value,
   b.value
from tbl a, tbl b
where a.id=b.id and
   a.value <> b.value
```

I get double comparison result

```
id id value value
1  1   a      b
1  1   b      a
2  2   c      d
2  2   d      c
```

How to avoid duplicate comparison?

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<`:

```
select a.id, b.id, a.value, b.value
from tbl a join
     tbl b
     on a.id = b.id and a.value < b.value;
```